# my loop is not working correctly in C. any ideas?

Tags: c, loops

I am new to C as of yesterday and I am trying to create a loop that will take ten characters, then print out how many "a"s are in it. no matter how many "a"s are in the string, it prints out 0. any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
       char string[10];
   int c = 0;
   int loop = 0;

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);


for (loop = 0; loop >10; ++loop)
 { 
    if (string[c] = 'a')
    {
     ++c;
    }
 }
      printf("A occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `gets`.

Comment: Look very closely at `for (loop = 0; loop >10; ++loop)` again. Take as long as you need.

Comment: `loop >10` --> `string[loop] != '\0'`, `string[c] = 'a'` --> `string[loop] == 'a'`

Comment: `printf("A occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c);` is misleading. It should be `printf("'a' occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c);`

Comment: Why all the downvotes? What's wrong with this question? OP is a beginner and I believe he can't figure out the silly mistake. Apart from that, the question has everything it needs, including a clear problem description and complete source code that replicates the problem easily.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You'll probably get warnings, improve your code till there is none. Then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`), it  is a mandatory skill (you could `run` your program `step` by step, add `breakpoint`s, query `backtrace`s, `print` data, etc...)

Comment: General advise: your source of learning is bad, if they are teaching you to use gets. Learn from someone/something else instead. Ensure that you are learning modern C, your source of learning should at least cover the C99 standard, or better yet the C11 standard. And stay clear of strings until you have fully grasped the concepts of arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should read again how `for` loop works,

```
for (loop = 0; loop >10; ++loop)
               ^^^^^^^^
```

This condition of yours is false from the beginning, as `loop = 0`, which is not `>10`. Hence the `for` loop is never executed.

Plus, when you are comparing inside the `for` loop, you are using `loop` variable to iterate over the characters of `string`. And, to compare `==` is used, `=` is assignment operator. So,

```
if (string[c] = 'a')
```

this should be

```
if (string[loop] == 'a')
```

---

In one very good book I read, it is written that to avoid such errors, [always use the comparison in the other way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), for instance,

```
if ('a' == string[loop])
```

Even if you mistype and put `=` instead of `==`, you will get an error.

---

*As a side note, don't use `gets()` function. It has been deprecated. You can read about the [Morris Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) to understand what effects `gets()` can have.*

Comment: The gets function has been removed from the C language, which alone is a sound reason not to use it.

Comment: @Lundin Thanx, added.

Answer (score 2):

Very quickly few reviews on your code

1. ```
   /* Change */
   for (loop = 0; loop >10; ++loop)
   /* To */
   for (loop = 0; loop < 10; ++loop)
   ```
2. ```
   /* Change */
   if (string[c] = 'a')
   /* To */
   if (string[loop] == 'a')
   ```
3. ```
   /* Change */
   gets(string);
   /* To */ 
   fgets(string, 10, stdin);
   ```

Comment: `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);` has advantages.